# Recovering a Blender-engine project in Eevee

Tags: 3d-view, blender-internal-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I have an old Blender file with simple graphics, made with ver.2.79 (I think).

As a complete beginner, I wan't aware which engine it was using, but'm guessing it was the Blender Internal engine.

I've updated my Blender since then, and my current version has Eevee, but not the Blender engine - which has meant I can't produce the same graphic anymore.

When I open the file, the graphic looks similar to the original under Viewpoint Shading = Solid, but it's complete darkness under Viewpoint Shading = Rendered. And, as such, the rendered image os also pure black.

I have several more project in the same condition. How can I produce the original image from the Blender in the Eevee environment?

Here's the project in question:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tAN7vyhfIgIPQSl1YxXvvoALPdkFSkt4/view?usp=sharing

And here's the image I want to produce again:
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Answer (score 0):

[image]
adjects your world's tab setting brighter our darker as you want.

Comment: Thanks, this improved - I changed the color to white (#FFFFFF) and at least now I can see the graphic:) But, it doesn't look quite the same. The color is a bit pale as compared to the original. If I change the color to anything other than that, the pale-ness goes away but I also need some pale-ness in some places. In other words, I need some contrast which I can't seem to recover in this method. Is there any other suggestions you can give?